# When does the number of signed intersections change for a continuous curve?

Tags: general-topology, curves

Suppose that I have a function $SI_p(\theta, \Gamma)$, $\Gamma : [0, 2 \pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is an oriented closed and continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $SI_p(\theta, \Gamma)$ gives the total amount of intersections with a ray at $p$ oriented by $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$. $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We can assume $p = (0,0)$ without loss of generality because we can just translate $\Gamma$. The sign of an intersection can be determined whether the ray intersects from the left or the right of the curve. The picture below shows what I mean by "Signed intersection" (albeit on an open-curve, but the concept is the same)
[image: Signed Intersections]

Now also defined $I_p(\theta, \Gamma)$ where $I_p$ is the total amount of intersections (ignores the sign).

If we start at $\theta = 0$ and increase it, for a given $p$ and $\Gamma$, can we show that the value of $SI_p$ can only change when the value of $I_p$ changes? Further, I think $SI_p$ is constant for closed curve (up to intersections where the curve is tangent to the ray) and only changes at the $\theta$ pointing towards the endpoints for open-curves. But I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: You should have stronger conditions than continuity, to avoid fractals. Another issue: the case where the ray includes a line segment of the curve.

Comment: You probably want your curve to be $C^1$ (or at least piecewise $C^1$) so that you can think about transversality of the rays to the curve. (This can be phrased in terms of the derivative of the projection mapping from the curve to the unit circle.)